# Use string from prop to import and display a component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm importing both `SignIn` and `Join` components when really I only need to import one of them. The name of the one I want to import is found on `state.showModal` How do import only the one I need?

Then when I come to display these components I'm doing...

```
          {showModal === 'SignIn' && <SignIn />}
          {showModal === 'Join' && <Join />}
```

This also seems weird can I do something like

```
<showModal />
```

The complete code snippet is below....

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { LayoutShape } from '../interfaces/state';
import { SignIn } from '../components/SignIn';
import { Join } from '../components/Join';

export interface PropsShape {
  children: ReactElement;
  state: LayoutShape;
  isSignedIn?: boolean;
}

const Layout = ({ children, state, isSignedIn }: PropsShape): ReactElement => {
  const {
    showNavAlert,
    isNavVisable,
    isFooterVisable,
    showFooterAlert,
    showModal,
    showLeftMenu,
    showRightMenu,
  } = state;
  return (
    <div className='Layout'>
      {showModal != 'none' && (
        <div className='Layout--modal' data-testid='showModal'>
          {showModal === 'SignIn' && <SignIn />}
          {showModal === 'Join' && <Join />}
        </div>
      )}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is conditional rendering in React and it is very common https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

instead of having a variable showModal that is a string, it could be a React component if you intend a more generic behavior inside the component:

```
import { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { LayoutShape } from '../interfaces/state';
import { SignIn } from '../components/SignIn';
import { Join } from '../components/Join';

export interface PropsShape {
  children: ReactElement;
  state: LayoutShape;
  isSignedIn?: boolean;
}

const Layout = ({ children, state, isSignedIn }: PropsShape): ReactElement => {
  const {
    showNavAlert,
    isNavVisable,
    isFooterVisable,
    showFooterAlert,
    Modal,
    showLeftMenu,
    showRightMenu,
  } = state;
  return (
    <div className='Layout'>
      {Modal != null && (
        <div className='Layout--modal' data-testid='showModal'>
          <Modal />}
        </div>
      )}
```

Depending on how your logic is implemented you could also have a proxy component that does the mapping between showModal and your component, but to my knowledge, you will always have to handle your conditional rendering somewhere in your code. Having it in the rendering as you did might be the best solution.